# matplotlib-problem with real-time update of figure in a loop

Tags: matplotlib, figure, real-time-updates

I want to plot 4 blocks where their colors are randomly changed to white or red. However when I code as below, the previous colors remain unchanged until all the four blocks are red.

```
from numpy import random, round
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, show, \
     close, clf, cla, ion, ioff, pause


LDX = [100, 100, 150, 150]
LDY = [50, 100, 50, 100]

fig = figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0.125, 0.1, 0.7, 0.8])
ion()
for ii in range(100):
    randperm = round(random.rand(len(LDX)))
    for i in range(len(LDX)):
        ldx = LDX[i]
        ldy = LDY[i]    
        h11, = ax.plot(
            [ldx-25, ldx+25, ldx+25,
             ldx-25, ldx-25], 
            [ldy+25, ldy+25, ldy-25,
             ldy-25, ldy+25],
            color='k')    
    for i in range(len(LDX)):
        if randperm[i]==1:
            ldx = LDX[i]
            ldy = LDY[i]
            h12, = ax.fill(
                [ldx-25, ldx+25, ldx+25,
                 ldx-25, ldx-25], 
                [ldy+25, ldy+25, ldy-25,
                 ldy-25, ldy+25],
                color='r')
    fig.show()
    fig.canvas.draw()
    fig.canvas.flush_events()
    pause(0.001)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the guidance and comments by @BreandanA, I managed to find the answer as follow:

```
ion()
fig = figure()
for j in range(100):
    LDX = [100, 100, 150, 150]
    LDY = [50, 100, 50, 100]
    randperm = round(random.rand(len(LDX)))
    clf()
    ax = fig.add_axes([0.125, 0.1, 0.7, 0.8])
    for i in range(len(LDX)):
        ldx = LDX[i]
        ldy = LDY[i]    
        h11, = ax.plot(
            [ldx-25, ldx+25, ldx+25,
            ldx-25, ldx-25], 
            [ldy+25, ldy+25, ldy-25,
            ldy-25, ldy+25],
            color='k')
    for i in range(len(LDX)):
        if randperm[i]==1:
            ldx = LDX[i]
            ldy = LDY[i]
            h12, = ax.fill(
                [ldx-25, ldx+25, ldx+25,
                ldx-25, ldx-25], 
                [ldy+25, ldy+25, ldy-25,
                ldy-25, ldy+25],
                color='r')
    draw_all()
    pause(0.001)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

With some small edits to the code you provided, you can get the desired result.

```
from numpy import random, round
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, show, \
    close, clf, cla, ion, ioff, pause

for j in range(100):
    LDX = [100, 100, 150, 150]
    LDY = [50, 100, 50, 100]
    fig = figure()
    ax = fig.add_axes([0.125, 0.1, 0.7, 0.8])
    randperm = round(random.rand(len(LDX)))

    for i in range(len(LDX)):
        ldx = LDX[i]
        ldy = LDY[i]    
        h11, = ax.plot(
            [ldx-25, ldx+25, ldx+25,
            ldx-25, ldx-25], 
            [ldy+25, ldy+25, ldy-25,
            ldy-25, ldy+25],
            color='k')
    for i in range(len(LDX)):
        if randperm[i]==1:
            ldx = LDX[i]
            ldy = LDY[i]
            h12, = ax.fill(
                [ldx-25, ldx+25, ldx+25,
                ldx-25, ldx-25], 
                [ldy+25, ldy+25, ldy-25,
                ldy-25, ldy+25],
                color='r')

    show(block=False)
    pause(0.5)
```

Comment: Thank you @BrendanA for your reply; Actually this is not the case. You have changed the location of randperm. I want to generate 4 binary numbers indicating the 4 blocks to be red or white. And in a loop with 100 iteration, at each time these 4 numbers are generated and are plotted. But I want to update the colors real-time.

Comment: Edited my answer!

Comment: Thank you @BrendanA. That is great. The edited code solved the problem. Actually I was looking for a way to not close the plotting window during run. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Im honestly not sure. I did find this package that might give you that functionality though? https://github.com/stsievert/python-drawnow

Comment: Thank you @BrendanA. Using the provided package, I managed to find the answer. It is now added as a new answer.